# Short story where it's normal to live stream deaths; salesman has to convince patients to use his company for it

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for the name of a short story where it follows a salesman going to a hospital to convince a dying patient to sign up with his company to broadcast the patient's experience as he dies in real time, a norm in this setting.  I'm fairly certain he fails and has to call in a higher up in his company, a 'closer' that describes the exchange of sharing the patient's dying experience better, and manages to sign the patient up. Judging on the description of tech and vernacular, maybe it was written in the 50s/60s.  I read it as an excerpt online, so don't know if it was from a magazine or anthology, but though I don't remember the website it seemed to collect pulp 50s/60s stories together.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is the death experience broadcast or is it recorded?  Do you recall if you read this in a magazine, an anthology, or online?

Comment: Thanks for the questions.  The death experience is being broadcasted to an undescribed audience, patrons of the salesman's company.  I read the short story as an excerpt online, so I don't know if it was originally published in an anthology or magazine, but it was in print much earlier than the internet and collected to the site I read it on.

Comment: Can you give a link to the site you read it on?

Comment: I've read it but can't remember the name/writer. IIRC it's because the patient has terminal stomach cancer and the viewers can subscribe to "feel" the pain....the patient's family has to decide whether to get handsomely paid to let the victim suffer excruciating pain or instead opt for pain relief and get paid nothing

Comment: Could this have been an excerpt from Robert Sheckley's 1959 novel "Immortality, Inc"? the novel takes place in a future where the soul and afterlife have been defined by science, and human experience can be recorded as entertainment. "Immortality, Inc" served as the source material for the 1992 film "Freejack", although the movie only covers a small portion of the novel.

Comment: It's an early Silverberg, Danny Mc G's description is completely accurate. Can't recall the title now, sadly.

Comment: Oh yes, The Pain Peddlers. Somebody else make the answer, please, it's hard to type on smartphone.

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dragan Milosevic identified it in the comments as "The Pain Peddlers" ([ISFDB](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?52637)) by Robert Silverberg. From [this review](https://sciencefictionruminations.com/2012/12/18/book-review-needle-in-a-timestack-robert-silverberg-1966/):

> In Silverberg’s short story the media purchases painful experiences by offering money to individuals about to undergo expensive and extremely painful operations.  Of course, the amount of money offered is contingent on the quality of the pain experienced — and thus, the less the anesthesia the more the cash.  The pain is “recorded” and sold to adoring fans.